How is the computational power defined in Quatum Computing?
In classical data centers, the computational power is expressed as function of the number of executed tasks per second as follows :
$$P(\lambda)=P_{idle}+(P_{peak}-P_{idle})\cdot(\lambda/CPU_{capacity})$$ where

$P_{idle}$ is the power used when the sever is idle

$P_{peak}$ is the power used at the peak usage of the server

$\frac{\lambda}{CPU_{capacity}}$ is the usage ratio of the server where the CPU capacity is expressed in MIPS


Is there any similar equations in quatum computing that relates the consumed power to the number of executed tasks?
My goal is to compare the energy-efficiency of classical data centers and quantum data centers.

Could you please explain meaning of individual terms in the formula?

@MartinVesely I added the definition of the used terms. Thank you !

A simple answer to this question cannot be given as we have not discovered the "transistor" in quantum computing. Possible solutions or hardware implementations are:

Ion Traps
Superconducting Qubits
Photons
Cold Neutral Atoms
Topological Qubits

All of these will have different energy requirements to do one computation. However, most implementations use dilution refrigerators which consume about 5-10 kW and larger fridges consume 20 kW+.

You might want to take a look at the report from the Homeland Security R&D department, which gives a formula for estimating the power consumption of a quantum computer:

Energy consumed = runtime × (number of qubits) × (average power
consumed per qubit)
Here, the power per qubit includes not only the power directly consumed by each qubit to
perform basic logic operations, but also all power consumption by hardware overhead, such as
classical co-processing, cooling, and other forms of hardware systems control.

In the report, they are specifically interested in the resource estimates of quantum computers that can break RSA.
According to Homeland, the ballpark electricity bill for breaking one public key is $64000, and it takes 125MW of power.

Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the numerical value of the average power consumed per qubit was not reported in the paper because; as the authors mention; it depends on the considered architecture. Moreover, I want similar metrics to the classical data center so that I can compare the energy-efficiency of classical data centers and quantum data centers.
